# How can I use networkx to create a better visualisation of an undirected graph?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

The code below creates a graph which is unreadable.

Is there a way to better present the network>

```
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(ps_nb.values)

labels = ps_nb.columns.values
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, dict(zip(range(len(labels)), labels)))

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

[image: Undirected Graph produced from Pandas adjacency matrix]

Comment: You might find this answer useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919360/make-networkx-plot-look-nice/60919508#60919508

Answer (score 1):

Try different [layouts](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html?highlight=layout#module-networkx.drawing.layout). For example,

```
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, pos=nx.spring_layout(G))
```